# How to get MS Word files detail in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-office

I'm trying to get detail of All open files using C#

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp;
   wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
   wordApp =(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
     for (int i = 0; i < wordApp .Windows.Count; i++)
       {
         string title;
         object a = i + 1;
         objWord.Windows[a].Activate();
         string fullName  =wordApp.Windows[a].Document.FullName.ToString();
        }
```

at first time it works fine, and give me correct objWord.window.count but after running program 2,3 time , it always shows zero count. even

Comment: Probably because you create a new instance of WordApp and then try to retrieve the current one. Instead put your `wordApp = ...GetActiveObject(..)` into a try catch. After the catch check if wordApp is null and only create a new instance if you need one. I don't know why you'd nee a new instance as it would always have 0 documents...

Comment: your question seems incomplete

Comment: @AbdurRahim my question is why my above code return me zero count while i've some files opened

Answer (score 1):

The issue likely arises from you creating a new instance of Word.Application and then trying to retrieve the current instance. This is confusing and I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Instead you should put your attempt to get the current instance inside a try/catch like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = null;

try
{
     wordApp =(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
}
catch
{
    // Handle exceptions here or ignore the error, your choice
    MessageBox.Show("Could not find an existing instance of Word");
}

// READ THIS CAREFULLY
// If you didn't already get an instance of Word then create one
// I don't understand why you would do this as it would have 0 documents
if (wordApp == null)
{
    // I would not do this part, if you create a new instance you'll have 0 documents
    wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
}

// Rest of your code goes here...
```

Comment: here it give me error if (wordApp == null) use of unassigned local variable wordApp

Comment: My mistake. Fixed it now. I forgot to assign wordApp as null on the first line.  Try now.

Comment: it still gives me zero count(wordApp.Windows.Count). although I have opened a file

Comment: Are you sure you have carefully read what I've said? To me it still sounds like your call to `GetActiveObject` is returning null so you're creating a new instance with 0 documents. If I open a Word document and use this code it correctly returns 1, if I open another and run the code again I get 2 and so on. I've put a MessageBox in the catch to prove if this is the case. If it's still not working then I'm not sure why as this code works fine.

Comment: when i exit all background processes it again return me right number of objects. my scenario is I'm opening document via button click .

Comment: OK, well you need to put that in your question and show the code for it or of course you'll get the wrong answer...

Comment: GC.Collect(); after adding this in start , i get right count everytime.. still i dont know what is logic behind

Comment: Until you should your full code then nobody can answer this for you. You've only provided part of the picture which is why you get part of the answer. Glad you got it fixed with GC.Collect, there's no harm in calling that method if it helps you.